# How to avoid the display of multiple alert windows in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, alert

I have a timer in my application. For every 30 min, it will hit the web services and fetch the data and updates the UI. The application was working fine till yesterday. Suddenly, because of some issue, the web services were not available for some time. During that period, Application displayed the RPC Error multiple times(More than 100 alert boxes) in alert window. Because of this alert boxes, my application was hanged and i was not able to do anything.

I have tried several approaches, but nothing worked.Finally, I have tried to use a flag. In all the approaches, this looked promising. so i have implemented it.Basically, in this approach whenever we open an alert we will set a flag.While opening and closing alert we will reset this flag. But it didn't work as expected. Is there any approach, which can help us in avoiding multiple alert windows.

Please help me, to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write wrapper for opening alerts, and use only this wrapper, not Alert.show in the code:

```
public class AlertWrapper {

   private static var lastAlert:Alert;

   public static function showAlert(text:String, title:String):void {
       if (lastAlert) {
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(lastAlert);
            //or
            //return; //ignore last alert
       }
       lastAlert = Alert.show(text, title, null, 4, onAlertClose);
   }

   private static function onAlertClose(event:CloseEvent):void {
       lastAlert = null;
   }
}
```

Imports are missing, but I hope the idea is clear.

Comment: Giving some error. I am not able to post the complete error here.   Error
 at mx.managers::SystemManager/updateLastActiveForm()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:5087]
 at mx.managers::SystemManager/activateForm()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2352]
 at mx.managers::SystemManager/activate()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2307]
 at mx.managers::FocusManager/creationCompleteHandler()[C:\autobuild\..\mx\managers\FocusManager.as:1592] ......

Comment: So it fails to remove Alert? I don't know how to do that yet (requires testing). Maybe a simple try/catch will help. Comment out line `PopUpManager.removePopUp(lastAlert)` and uncomment `return`, it will ignore last alert until first is closed.

Comment: i think, as Alxx is saying to use try catch, would be best, i do have these sort of situations, when some server interation is goin on, See run time errors are best handled using try catch blocks,

Comment: try... catch didn't work. I think it's SDK issue. I have compiled the same with SDK 3.4. Now it's working fine. It's not working with 3.2.